How do i define the "quality" of variable combinations in C#/Unity?
I was wondering how to define the "quality" of a combination of variables in a efficient and comprehensible way.
example for a movie - i have 2 arrays :
string[] topic = {"war", "medieval", "space", "drugs"};
string[] genre = {"action", "comedy", "romance", "drama"};

where it is possible to have 1 or 2 topics and up to 3 genres. and those combinations can be for example 0-3 (very bad to very good).
And how to handle that war & action is a good combination but war & action + romance is a bad one for example?
Is the only way to make lots of lists with all possible combinations of topics and genres ?
Wouldnt this be very bad if you want to extend this and also explodes in size with alot of topics and genres ?
thanks in advance!

depends how much you were likely to edit it, but you could either assign a value to each topic/genre and then do an array of x,y and have a value of 0-3, but if you then insert something earlier it would whack your settings..

This also sounds very subjective ;) So who defines which combinations are good or bad and based on what exactly?

I can think of a structure where you define known bads and goods for each other item (assume neutral if not defined) ... but yeah this will be hard to define I guess ... something like e.g. class Topic { public string Name; pubilc List<Topic> goodTopics; List<Topic> badTopics; public List<Genre> goodGenres; public List<Genre> badGenres; } ... or even a more central approach where the good and bad combos are simply stored in Dictionary or even some more complex matrix .. depending on the amount of items good be some bitmask maybe
